# subprocess reading multiline

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to read out this text given from a command:

```
System Data At this Computer
    Sector: id1
        Name: name1
        Data: data1
    Sector: id2
        Name: name2
        Data: data2
```

Want to put this output into a variable, but there is only `System Data At this Computer` in the variable.

Im reading it with:

```
var = subprocess.check_output(["./android", "list", "avd"], cwd= #path#)
```

What do I wrong???

Comment: Your code looks right. Is it possible that the command sends part of output to stderr instead of stdout?

Comment: How can i read this out or check this?

Comment: Try to run it in command line: "./android list avd > /dev/null" will output just stderr, and "./android list avd 2> /dev/null" will output stdout w/o stderr.

Comment: Don't work...an other idea?

Comment: How exactly it didn't work? Did the commands produce some output?

Comment: Yes! At the command-line the same... at the variable again olny the first line..

Comment: I tried to simulate your "android" command behavior with "echo", see http://ideone.com/N1q1NL.
Looks like there's nothing wrong with subprocess.check_output() in case of multiline output. Perhaps you should check "android" behavior more carefully.

Comment: ANd why dont work it?

Comment: "dont work" is not very descriptive. [edit] your question and tell us explicitely: what is the exact command that you've used, what do you see in a terminal, what do you get in the `var` variable (`print(repr(var))`) for each command that @zag mentioned.